# Update a field or create it if it is not present in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, express, nosql

I have a collection named users and it already has many documents inside it but some documents are missing the field  name `newUnreadMessage` of type `boolean` . I want to update this field to false if it is already present . And if it is not present i want to create this field inside that respective document and set its value to false

I tried doing

> User.find({ builder: builderId }).find({ _id: data.userId }).update({
> newUnreadMessage: false }, { $set: { "newUnreadMessage": false } })

I dont know why but it is not creating a new field in case it is not present . I am new to MongoDb please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the option "{ multi: true }" to your update operation to be able to update the multiple documents you need to , check the update command sintax [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#syntax)

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E19U8DYTr3r)

```
db.collection.update({
  builder: "b1"
},
{
  $set: {
   "newUnreadMessage": false
 }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Indeed also as @Yong Shun mentioned if your search criteria match newUnreadMessage: false , you will not be able to modify documents missing the key newUnreadMesage ...

Comment: Other than multiple documents not update, the filter criteria of update query based on post owner's current code: `{ newUnreadMessage: false }`, this will only update those documents with the `newUnreadMessage` field is `false`, but not the document with the `newUnreadMessage` field does not exist.